# Is Find in place of Vlookup for large 20k row sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a large project consisting of a series of forms, and several macros. The main report that I need to update month after month, is 21K rows and growing. It collects all 12 months of updates in 12 separate columns.  To complete an "update", I must match a part number from the main file (21k rows are all part numbers and their info)contained in column "A", and match it to another report generated by part number (this time contained in column "B") and if it matches (NEEDS TO BE EXACT MATCH), return the following:

Place the value of column 9 sht1 to sht column designated by variable

Place the value of column 7 sht1 to sht column 27

Place the value of column 11 sht 1 to sht column 34

each time it matches, cycling row by row, till last part number contained in Column A, in sht.

The following code works, but I am wondering is there a better way I should be writing this? Is this the best for processing speed and accuracy? I just realized in another block of code, this same method was not performing an exact match, which now has thrown a red flag, for me to maybe change my methodology. I absolutely need this to be accurate, and it must match EXACTLY, or leave the contents blank.

```
'Set variable with cell range value for ABC Code based on month selected by User

Dim ABCCodeCell As Integer
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks(vFileName1) 'ABC Matrix File
Set wb2 = Workbooks(vFileName2) 'Cycle Count Remainder Browse File
Set sht = wb1.Worksheets(1) 'ABC Matrix File
Set sht1 = wb2.Worksheets(1) 'Cycle Count Remainder Browse File

lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Select Case ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value
    Case "January": ABCCodeCell = 21
    Case "February": ABCCodeCell = 23
    Case "March": ABCCodeCell = 25
    Case "April": ABCCodeCell = 3
    Case "May": ABCCodeCell = 5
    Case "June": ABCCodeCell = 7
    Case "July": ABCCodeCell = 9
    Case "August": ABCCodeCell = 11
    Case "September": ABCCodeCell = 13
    Case "October": ABCCodeCell = 15
    Case "November": ABCCodeCell = 17
    Case "December": ABCCodeCell = 19
End Select

'Execute Find (Vlookup)


On Error Resume Next
For i = 2 To lRow
If sht.Cells(i, 1).value <> "" Then
    Set rng = sht1.Range("B:B").Find(sht.Cells(i, 1).value)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
         sht.Cells(i, ABCCodeCell).value = sht1.Cells(rng.Row, 9).value
         sht.Cells(i, 27).value = sht1.Cells(rng.Row, 7).value
         sht.Cells(i, 34).value = sht1.Cells(rng.Row, 11).value
    End If
End If
Next
```

Comment: @Tim Williams This is it. I just had to rewrite it, as I posted it before, but no one responded, so I deleted it after a few days. Thank you! - Athena, aka SharePoint0508

Comment: It looks good to me... Is it running too slow at the moment? Are you using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False, Application.Cursor = xlWait`, etc.? Is anything particularly not working? This might be a better question for Code Review.

Comment: *I just realized in another block of code, this same method was not performing an exact match,*, What did you mean by this?

Comment: The "exact match" with a `Find` is done by specifying the `LookAt:=xlWhole` parameter - don't rely on that being the method last used by the user (they may have used `LookAt:=xlPart`).  (See @TimWilliams comment to your previous question.)

Comment: I'd suggest removing the "On Error resume Next" since it can hide potential problems you probably would want to know about.

Comment: @dwirony  in another macro, linked to this same project, I used this same block of code, and just altered the columns, and what it would return, and used a different variable. In that scenario, if it matched the value, it would return a "1" in a specified column.  I quickly learned it wasn't performing an "EXACT MATCH".  I am still in the learning curve here, and didn't realize it would take from the last performed action by the user. It was matching 11111-12 with 11111-1 for example. After researching, learning about "LookAt:" I realized what was wrong. But clueless on how to revise my code

Comment: I then posted a question (not this one, a different one) and Tim helped me to better understand. I must have an exact match of the entire cell contents in all instances where I applied this same block/same methodology.  Leaving me to revise everything. I understand the concept, I am always stuck at the syntax, of how the statements should be written. My background is being Goddess of SharePoint, lol :) writing workflows and such, which can be similar, but expressed differently to achieve results.

Comment: I know it is bad practice, but I do want to say thank you to @Tim Williams, and YowE3k for all your guidance and responses to my questions. I appreciate the explanations to help me better understand. I know that takes time, and I am thankful. Your knowledge is not lost on me..  I appreciate it.

Comment: @SharePoint0508 - it's not bad practice to say thanks!  It's always satisfying to help out someone who want to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't comment on whether your code is the best possible code for speed, etc, as that isn't really on-topic for Stack Overflow - those sort of questions should be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

I will however answer re your "(NEEDS TO BE EXACT MATCH)" comments:

Excel permits users to specify various options when performing a Find:

[image]

Most (all?) of those options are remembered and used by default in the next Find, be that a manual Find executed by the user, or a programmed `Find` within your VBA code.

Your current find (`sht1.Range("B:B").Find(sht.Cells(i, 1).value)`) does not specify any parameters other than the `What` parameter and will therefore use whatever the user last used for the values of the `LookIn`, `LookAt` and `MatchCase` parameters.

If you want to perform an exact match, and you don't trust the users to not have done a partial match prior to running your code, you should explicitly state what options you wish to use.

I would suggest that you change your `Find` to be:

```
Set rng = sht1.Range("B:B").Find(What:=sht.Cells(i, 1).Value, _
                                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                 LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                 MatchCase:=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Running `Find()` in a large loop is quite slow compared to using `Match()`.

For example, looking up 2000 values in a column of 20,000 distinct values:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim i As Long, f As Range, t, m, n As Long

    t = Timer
    For i = 1 To 2000
        Set f = Columns(1).Find(what:="Prod_" & Format(i, "000000"), _
                                lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            n = n + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Find", Timer - t, "found " & n

    t = Timer
    n = 0
    For i = 1 To 2000
        m = Application.Match("Prod_" & Format(i, "000000"), Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            n = n + 1
            'here m = the row with the matched value, so copy from this row
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Match", Timer - t, "found " & n

End Sub
```

Output:

```
Find           19.75781     found 2000
Match          1.46875      found 2000
```

Comment: Would the `Match` be even faster if you read the search range into an array first?

Comment: Hmmm - appears not - I get 14.32 for Find, 1.11 for Match, and 13.06 for Match against an array (with time to read it into the array being shown as `0`)

Comment: @YowE3K - Match is faster (about 10x) against the worksheet than the array (edit: which you already figured out)

Comment: Relevant: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: Looping through the 20,000 element array rather than using Match to look in it got the time down to about 3.5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

If sht has not formula cells,  Using Variant Array is faster.

```
Sub test()
'Set variable with cell range value for ABC Code based on month selected by User

    Dim ABCCodeCell As Integer
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb1 = Workbooks(vFileName1) 'ABC Matrix File
    Set wb2 = Workbooks(vFileName2) 'Cycle Count Remainder Browse File
    Set sht = wb1.Worksheets(1) 'ABC Matrix File
    Set sht1 = wb2.Worksheets(1) 'Cycle Count Remainder Browse File

    lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Select Case ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.Value
        Case "January": ABCCodeCell = 21
        Case "February": ABCCodeCell = 23
        Case "March": ABCCodeCell = 25
        Case "April": ABCCodeCell = 3
        Case "May": ABCCodeCell = 5
        Case "June": ABCCodeCell = 7
        Case "July": ABCCodeCell = 9
        Case "August": ABCCodeCell = 11
        Case "September": ABCCodeCell = 13
        Case "October": ABCCodeCell = 15
        Case "November": ABCCodeCell = 17
        Case "December": ABCCodeCell = 19
    End Select

    'Execute Find (Vlookup)
    Dim vDB, rngDB As Range, r As Long, c As Integer '<~~ vDB is Variant array
    Dim rngData As Range
    With sht
        r = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        c = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set rngDB = .Range("a2", .Cells(r, c))
        vDB = rngDB
    End With
    With sht1
        Set rngData = .Range("b1", .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With


    'On Error Resume Next

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
    'If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        If vDB(i, 1) <> "" Then
            Set rng = rngData.Find(vDB(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                'sht.Cells(i, ABCCodeCell).Value = sht1.Cells(rng.Row, 9).Value
                vDB(i, ABCCodeCell) = rng.Offset(, 7)
                'sht.Cells(i, 27).Value = sht1.Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
                vDB(i, 27) = rng.Offset(, 5)
                'sht.Cells(i, 34).Value = sht1.Cells(rng.Row, 11).Value
                vDB(i, 34) = rng.Offset(, 9)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rngDB = vDB
End Sub
```